# Why MultipleChoiceField with widget CheckboxSelectMultiple could not stored into the database?

Tags: python, django

I have retrieved all the selected items in MiltiselectCheckbox successfully but could not able to store it into the data base.

When I check the database it stored a series of None. Like None, None, None.

This is my forms.py code snippet for the field.

```
list_items = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
        label="Select Feature Predictor:"
    )
```

Here is my Models.py code snippet:

```
list_items = models.TextField()
```

also tried

```
list_items = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

in my views.py i have this code:

```
list_items = request.POST.getlist(u'list_items')
str_checked_values = ', '.join(check_values)

#printed to check if it retrieved the checked items
#and it does
print('check_values', str_checked_values) 
#assign to the database column
predModel.list_items = str_checked_values
```

The code should be able to store the selected values from the CheckBox as a string into the database...

Comment: Please show the model, and the rest of the view. What is `predModel`? Do you save it?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed predModel is your model instance.

If it is your model instance, you can just do:

```py
predModel.list_items = str_checked_values
predModel.save()
```

OR if it is your model,

just do:

```py
predModel.objects.create(list_items=str_checked_values,....)
```